# Choosing letters at random from A,A,A,B,B,R,R,R

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We arrange letters A,A,A,B,B,R,R,R randomly. Find a probability that they will form sequence: RABARBAR.

I have an answer and it is: $$\frac{1}{{{8}\choose{3}}{{5}\choose{2}}{{3}\choose{3}} }$$

Is this a correct answer if so why is that?

Comment: The answer is correct. There are various equivalent forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 $A$s and $8$ possible spots for them, so the probability that they will be in the correct spots is $\frac{1}{8\choose3}$. Given that this has happened, there are $5$ spots for the two $B$'s so the probability that they are in the correct spot is $\frac{1}{5\choose2}$. Given that both of these have happened, the $R$s must be in the correct spots, i.e. this event has probability $1=\frac{1}{3\choose3}$. Now combine these conditional probabilities and find that this event will happen with probability $$\frac{1}{{8\choose 3}{5\choose 2} {3\choose 3} }.$$

Answer (score 0):

The total ways are $\frac{8!}{3!.3!.2!}$ so the probability of RABARBAR is $\frac{3!.3!.2!}{8!}$

Comment: You don't need the 1/3!3!2! anymore. 1/8! would be a random permutation of 8 different object chance.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the solution as 3!3!2!/8!

Out of all 8! permutations, you can have any permutation of 3 A's, 3 R's and 2 B's.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of permutations is $8!=40320$, and this repeats each unique sequence $3!3!2!=72$ times.

Therefore there are $\frac{40320}{72}=560$ different sequences, and so **RABARBAR** appears with probability $1/560\approx0.0017857$.